# Elasticsearch geospatial map, not able to render Linestring

Tags: elasticsearch, maps, geospatial

the elasticsearch index contains json as below, only relevant element is show

```
"geoLocation": { 
"coordinates": [ [ -90.66487121582031, 42.49201965332031 ], [ -90.66487884521484, 42.49202346801758 ], [ -90.6648941040039, 42.492034912109375 ], [ -90.66490936279297, 42.49203872680664 ], [ -90.66492462158203, 42.492042541503906 ], [ -90.6649398803711, 42.49204635620117 ], [ -90.66495513916016, 42.49205017089844 ], [ -90.66497039794922, 42.4920539855957 ], [ -90.66498565673828, 42.492061614990234 ], [ -90.66500854492188, 42.492061614990234 ], [ -90.66502380371094, 42.49207305908203 ], [ -90.6650390625, 42.4920654296875 ] ], 
"type": "linestring" 
},
```

The template for generating the mapping is as below

```
PUT _template/template_1?include_type_name=true
{
  "index_patterns": ["metromind-its-alerts-day2-*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2
  },
 "mappings": {
        "logs": {
            "properties": {
                "geoLocation": {
                    "type": "geo_shape"
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

the mapping generated is shown below

[mapping showing the geoLocation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP9ob.png)

When Kibana Maps are used it detects the geo_shape

[Kibana Map to render Linestring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMqk0.png)

Note However no Linestring is rendered, please suggest the resolution

Comment: elastic and kiibana
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.1", }

Answer (score 0):

The line string is there, in Dubuque IL, it's just that it's extra small at the scale of the earth.

Just click on the following icon and Elastic Map will focus on it and you'll see it:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes the lines are there, I had to manually focus the location as the version 7.6.1 autofocus icon not showing up

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense!